# jquery function is sending alert as per the total no of records in mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have several records to be retrieved from mysql table and each of the record will have delete button, for deletion im using the script below #1 or #2.

when im using #1 it gives alert 1 time when i click on delete button to delete any record, but when i use #2 it gives me alert 5 times if i have 5 record or gives alert as per the total number of records in the mysql table can anybody please fix the #2 becuase it is fulfilling my needs as i want.

**HTML/PHP Part**

```
<?php
include('inc/db.php');
$rest_menuC = mysql_query("select * from menu_items where status = 1");
while ($mitemC  = mysql_fetch_array($rest_menuC)){
    $mitem_idC  = $mitemC['id'];
    $mitem_enC  = $mitemC['ename'];
    $mitem_anC  = $mitemC['aname'];
    $mitem_fnC  = $mitemC['filename'];
    $mitem_ssC  = $mitemC['status'];
$order_temp =   mysql_query("select * from temp_cart where item_id = '".$mitem_idC."'  and ses_mem=113 order by id");
while ($torder = mysql_fetch_assoc($order_temp)) {
    $prITTD     =   $torder['id'];
    $prITTC     =   $torder['item_id'];
    $prIDTC     =   $torder['price_id'];
    $qtyT       =   $torder['qty'];     
    $pc1        =   $torder['pc1'];
    $pc2        =   $torder['pc2'];
    $pc3        =   $torder['pc3'];
    $pc4        =   $torder['pc4'];
    $pc5        =   $torder['pc5'];
    $pc6        =   $torder['pc6'];
    $pc7        =   $torder['pc7'];
    $pc8        =   $torder['pc8'];
    $pc9        =   $torder['pc9'];
    $pc10       =   $torder['pc10'];
    $pc11       =   $torder['pc11'];
    $pc12       =   $torder['pc12'];
?>
    <li>
        <div class="product-thumb">
        <img style="width:40px; height:40px;" src="images/rest_menu_items/<?php echo $mitem_fnC; ?>" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="product-name">
            <a href="#"><?php echo $mitem_enC; ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="qty-wrap">
            <span class="product-quantity">
                <span class="quantity">Qty. <?php echo $qtyT; ?></span> Price.
            </span>
            <span class="amount"><?php echo $prIDTC; ?></span>
<?php
    echo "<br><br>";
?>
<?php
$order_tempCHP      =   mysql_query("select * from choice_price
WHERE
 id IN('$pc1','$pc2','$pc3','$pc4','$pc5','$pc6','$pc7','$pc8','$pc9','$pc10','$pc11','$pc12') !=0
AND item_id = '".$prITTC."'");
$toarder = mysql_num_rows($order_tempCHP);
while ($torderCP    = mysql_fetch_assoc($order_tempCHP)) {
    $CPid   =   $torderCP['id'];
    $CPenm  =   $torderCP['ename'];
    $CPicd  =   $torderCP['choice_id'];
    $CPitd  =   $torderCP['item_id'];
    $CPlpr  =   $torderCP['price'];

//if ($pc1 > 0.000 || $pc2 > 0.000 || $pc3 > 0.000 || $pc4 > 0.000 || $pc5 > 0.000 || $pc6 > 0.000 || $pc7 > 0.000 || $pc8 > 0.000 || 
//$pc9 > 0.000 || $pc10 > 0.000 || $pc11 > 0.000 || $pc12 > 0.000){
$order_tempCHPa     =   mysql_query("select * from choice_price
WHERE
 id = '$pc2'
AND id != 0
AND item_id = '".$prITTC."'");
$toardera = mysql_num_rows($order_tempCHPa);
if ($toarder == 1){
?>
<div id="record-<?php echo $prITTC; ?>">
<span class="quantity"><font color="red" style="font-weight:bold;">Choices # <?php echo $CPicd; ?></font></span><br>
<span class="quantity"> <?php echo $CPenm; ?> # <?php echo $CPlpr; ?></span>
<!--<a href="#" onclick="ConfirmChoice(); return false;">X</a>-->
<a href="?delete=<?php echo $prITTC; ?>" class="deleteAS">X</a>
</div>
<?php }else{ ?>
<div id="record-<?php echo $prITTC; ?>">
<span class="quantity"><font color="red" style="font-weight:bold;">Choices # <?php echo $CPicd; ?></font></span><br>
<span class="quantity"> <?php echo $CPenm; ?> # <?php echo $CPlpr; ?></span>
<!--<a href="#" onclick="ConfirmChoice(); return false;">X</a>-->
<a href="?delete=<?php echo $prITTC; ?>" class="deleteAS">X</a>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
   </li>
```

**menu_cart_delete_item_choice.php**

```
$idA    = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ajax']);
$iidA   = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['delete']);
$delete = mysql_query("
UPDATE
    temp_cart
SET
    pc1 = 0
WHERE
    item_id = '".$iidA."'
AND
    id = '".$idA."'
AND
    ses_mem= 113
");
```

**#1**

```
function ConfirmChoice() {
var confirmText = "Are you sure you want to delete this object?";
    if(confirm(confirmText)) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"menu_cart_delete_item_choice.php?idSa=<?php echo $prITTD; ?>&iida=<?php echo $mitem_idC; ?>",
            success:function () {
            // Here goes something...
            },
        });
    }
}
```

**#2**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.deleteAS').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var confirmText = "Are you sure you want to delete this object?";
        if(confirm(confirmText)) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'menu_cart_delete_item_choice.php',
            data: 'ajax=<?php echo $prITTD; ?>&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
            beforeSend: function() {
                parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},100);
            },
            success: function() {
                parent.slideUp(100,function() {
                    parent.remove();
                });
            }
        });
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: please post olso your php code

Comment: show us your HTML content also. How your are printing html elements where you've placed your delete action.

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar i have edited my question please check the edited part

Comment: I Implemented your code at my end, it's working fine. I'm not getting `confirm alert` 5 times.

Comment: You get  "Are you sure you want to delete this object?" confirm alert 5 times when you click on **X**? Even after you click OK or Cancel you get alert 5 times?

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar  well either cancel or ok on both (X of Choice # not the above one)

Comment: I'm not getting any repeated alerts at my end. Please add the code of `menu_cart_delete_item_choice.php`. Also add complete block of your HTML/PHP code

Comment: Obligatory use `mysqli` rather than `mysql` comment...

Answer (score 0):

When you are using one class for multiple element Jquery finds all of them, you should use a function for that.

```
function deleteItem(e)
{

        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var confirmText = "Are you sure you want to delete this object?";
        if(confirm(confirmText)) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'menu_cart_delete_item_choice.php',
            data: 'ajax=<?php echo $prITTD; ?>&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
            beforeSend: function() {
                parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},100);
            },
            success: function() {
                parent.slideUp(100,function() {
                    parent.remove();
                });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your **#2** code like this and let me know what happens.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.deleteAS').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var confirmText = "Are you sure you want to delete this object?";
        if (confirm(confirmText)) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'menu_cart_delete_item_choice.php',
                data: 'ajax=<?php echo $prITTD; ?>&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-', ''),
                beforeSend: function () {
                    parent.animate({'backgroundColor': '#fb6c6c'}, 100);
                },
                success: function () {
                    parent.slideUp(100, function () {
                        parent.remove();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else{ return false; }
    });
});
```

Comment: No Bro. I tried every combination as per your code. I'm not getting multiple alerts. Now, To resolve this we have to do deeper debugging. If possible do view source code of your main page and post in your question. That way I will able to understand your complete html structure.